# Error while updating property 'coordinate' of a view managed by: AIRMapMarker (React native)

Tags: react-native

I have been searching the web for proper documentation in regards to this error, am in in no luck as i am unable to determine the cause of this error.

Here is the my entire code:

**First section:** setting the states

```
export default class Whereto extends Component<{}> {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        location: null,
        error: null,
        markers:[],

    };
}
```

**Second section** Component did Mount

```
componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    error: null,
                });

                //geocode api
                var myApiKey = '';

                fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&key=' + myApiKey)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((responseJson) => {
                        //console.log('ADDRESS GEOCODE is BACK!! => ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
                        var locationName = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(x => x.types.filter(t => t === 'administrative_area_level_2').length > 0)[0].short_name;
                        //console.log(locationName);
                        this.setState({
                            location: locationName,
                        })
                    })

                //nearby api
                var apiPlaceskey = '';
                //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY

                fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&radius=2000&type=bus_station&key=' + apiPlaceskey)
                    .then((respplaces) => respplaces.json())
                    .then((responseJson2) => {

                        const markers = responseJson2.results.map((result) => ({
                            latlng: {
                                latitude: result.geometry.location.lat,
                                longitude: result.geometry.location.lng,
                            }
                        }));

                        this.setState({ markers });
                    });


            },
            (error) => this.setState({error: error.message}),
            {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},

        );


    }
```

**Third section**: A function reserved when a a touchable button is tapped on my render and View section

```
fetchDirections = () => {
        //directions api
        var apiDirectionskey = '';
        //const {location} = this.state;
        const {latitude} = this.state;
        const {longitude} = this.state;

        fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&destination=' + goingto + '&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&key=' + apiDirectionskey)
            .then((resdirections) => resdirections.json())
            .then((responseJson3) => {

                console.log(responseJson3);

            });


        }

    render(){

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Mainlogo/>
                <TextInput style={styles.boxInput} underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' placeholder="Going To?"
                           underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                           onChangeText={(dest) => this.setState({goingto : dest})}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.fetchDirections.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={styles.textButton}> Go {this.props.type}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <MapView style={styles.map}
                         region={{
                             latitude: this.state.latitude,
                             longitude: this.state.longitude,
                             latitudeDelta: 0.02,
                             longitudeDelta: 0.02
                         }}
                >

                </MapView>

                <MapView.Marker
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: this.state.latitude,
                        longitude: this.state.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.02,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.02
                    }}
                    image={require('../img/my-pin-512.png')}
                    title={'you are here'}
                />

                {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={marker.latlng}
                        image={require('../img/busstop.png')}

                    />

                ))}





            </View>
        )

    }
}
```

To get to this stage a touchableopacity is tapped from my main profile page. I realised that i am using componendDidMount and a seperate fetch function to call another API call. It seems that it is not getting enough time to pupulate the states to cause the null values

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Set initial state values to 0 instead of null.

```js
this.state = {
  latitude:0,
  longitude: 0,
  latitudeDelta: 0.09,
  longitudeDelta: 0.02,
};
```

Comment: hi @Sunil, i am facing the exact same issue when i am updating the lat and lng with setState.. I also have initial state set to some coordinates and then i also tried your solution but the error still persists.. Any ideas..?

Comment: @ZainNazirButt Can you share your code and versions of react-native and react-native-maps

Comment: Hi @sunil, i resolved my issue, it was due to the fact that MapView initial region also requires latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta. By providing those the error was resolved.. I am using react-native-cli: 2.0.1 -- react-native: 0.54.4 -- react-native-maps: ^0.21.0

Answer (score 9):

**I was receiving the lat, lng value as props so what worked for me was:**

```
<Marker
coordinate={{
            longitude: longitude ? longitude : 0,
            latitude: latitude ? latitude : 0
          }}
title={'owner location'}
/>
```

Comment: Initially I was passing "mapRegion" state which consisted of latitude and longitude like coordinate={mapRegion}.

Later, I followed your one.

```
<Marker
            title="You"
            coordinate={{
              longitude: mapRegion.longitude ? mapRegion.longitude : 0,
              latitude: mapRegion.latitude ? mapRegion.latitude : 0,
            }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the initial value in **coordinates** from `null` to `[]` solved the issue.

```
<MapView.Polyline
    strokeWidth={2}
    strokeColor="#00ff00"
    coordinates={coords}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

passing this helped me solve this:

```
coordinate={{
     latitude: props && props.position && Number(props.position.latitude) ? Number(props.position.latitude) : 0,
     longitude: props && props.position && Number(props.position.longitude) ? Number(props.position.longitude) : 0 
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is this: while you are updating the `<Marker/>` component, make sure that you are not passing null in the coordinates' latitude or longitude.

I faced the same error while looping through an object, where some of my fields were empty. I solved it by defaulting to 0 whenever there was an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is the coordinate used in MapView, Markers, Circle etc... should be float/double value not string....

Usually {latitude: "27.123123",longitude: "85.2312321"}, is the problem should not be string should be {latitude: 27.123123,longitude: 85.2312321}

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was passing "mapRegion" state which consisted of latitude and longitude like coordinate={mapRegion}.

Later, I followed the below approach which should have null value if not fetched.

```
<Marker
        title="You"
        coordinate={{
          longitude: mapRegion.longitude ? mapRegion.longitude : 0,
          latitude: mapRegion.latitude ? mapRegion.latitude : 0,
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Marker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lat,
        longitude: origin.details.geometry.location.lng}}
      title={'Origin'}
    />
      <Marker
      coordinate={{
        latitude: destination.details.geometry.location.lat,
        longitude: destination.details.geometry.location.lng}}
      title={'Destination'}
    />
```

I might be late, but the trick above worked