# latlng cannot be null, a position is required. ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to add markers to my map. I want to have all the location data on a separate file so I'm trying to extract the coordinates from my data.json file. The latlng coordinates are in an array in the json file. Am I using the position attribute incorrectly?

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DestinationButton />
        <CurrentLocationButton
          cb={() => {
            this.centerMap();
          }}
        />
        <MapView
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          showsCompass={true}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          ref={(map) => {
            this.map = map;
          }}
          style={{ flex: 1, zIndex: 0 }}
        >
          {data.features.map((tc) => (
            <Marker
              key={tc.properties.NAME}
              position={{
                lat: tc.geometry.coordinates[1],
                lng: tc.geometry.coordinates[0],
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are giving a wrong prop to `<Marker/>` it should be **coordinate** instead of **position**. As per docs: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#rendering-a-list-of-markers-on-a-map

```js
<Marker 
  key={tc.properties.NAME} 
  coordinate={{
    latitude: tc.geometry.coordinates[1],
    longitude: tc.geometry.coordinates[0],
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Tried your code and i get this "Error while updating property 'coordinate' of a view managed by: AIRMapMarker null latitude"

Comment: your error in question is resolved, now make sure data you are mapping doesn't have any null value or initial state is not null. kindly refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941216/error-while-updating-property-coordinate-of-a-view-managed-by-airmapmarker-r

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out